# psboxit.sty not found MacTeX (mac osx)

Tags: installing, mactex, mac

Few days back, I had an installation of Mactex 2013 and it was working fine for my current writeup which included package psboxit.sty.

Due to some reasons, I had to remove that version (which I did manually). Yesterday, I installed the recent version of Mactex 2014 and tried to compile the same writeup but got an error message that psboxit.sty is not found.

psboxit.sty could be found in /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/misc209. But there is no folder names misc209 in /usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/.

Do I need to install some additional packages to get the desired .sty file?

Comment: Apparently the package has an unknown license which also means it isn't distributed as part of TeX Live (MacTeX). You can [grab the `.sty` file from CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/psboxit) and [install it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/23160).

Comment: @mvkorpel How exactly I can install it? Should I just copy the file in /usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/? I tried that too but its not working either.

Comment: I suggest you read [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1141/23160) to the question I already linked to. In short: You should not make manual modifications to `texmf-dist`, but copy the file to either the local or the home texmf tree instead. In case you choose the local tree, you must update the file name database with `mktexlsr` after copying the file.